# How to resolve NoClassDefFoundError while using Hadoop?

Tags: java, hadoop, noclassdeffounderror, camus

I am getting

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/linkedin/camus/etl/IEtlKey.

On running the command:

```
hadoop jar camus-etl-kafka-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar 
com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob -P camus.properties
```

I am getting the below exceptions..

```
2016-04-27 11:34:04.622 java[13567:351959] Unable to load realm mapping info from SCDynamicStore
[NativeCodeLoader] - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/linkedin/camus/etl/IEtlKey
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob.run(CamusJob.java:252)
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob.run(CamusJob.java:235)
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob.run(CamusJob.java:691)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at com.linkedin.camus.etl.kafka.CamusJob.main(CamusJob.java:646)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.linkedin.camus.etl.IEtlKey
```

I have included `camus-example-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar` in the classpath .

Please let me know if I am missing something .

Thanks in Advance

Soumyajit

Answer (score 0):

You should try to include `camus-api` you can find on this [LinkedIn's previous generation Kafka to HDFS pipeline](https://github.com/linkedin/camus) page, since the missing class is contained in this package, as you can see [here](https://github.com/linkedin/camus/tree/master/camus-api/src/main/java/com/linkedin/camus/etl).

Pay attention to other transitive dependencies that may be required by Camus.

In addition, to be sure that classes will be found in the classpath when you use the `hadoop jar` from command line, you can add the `libjars` command line option, as reported in [Using the libjars option with Hadoop](http://grepalex.com/2013/02/25/hadoop-libjars/):

> ```
> $ export LIBJARS=/path/jar1,/path/jar2
> $ hadoop jar my-example.jar com.example.MyTool -libjars ${LIBJARS} -mytoolopt value
> ```

It could be useful to know that Camus is going to be superseded by Gobblin:

> Camus is being phased out and replaced by Gobblin. For those using or
>   interested in Camus, we suggest taking a look at Gobblin.
>
> For instructions on Migrating from Camus to [Gobblin](https://github.com/linkedin/gobblin), please take
>   a look at [Camus Gobblin Migration](https://github.com/linkedin/gobblin/wiki/Camus-%E2%86%92-Gobblin-Migration).

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your suggestion . I have already added camus-api in the classpath , but still no luck ..Let me know if I am missing  anything..

Comment: yes.. Actually when I am running from IDE, it is not giving the exception. but when I am trying to run it from terminal, it is giving the same exception .